# iphone facebook friend status

Tags: iphone

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setValue:@"100000********" forKey:@"uid"];
    [params setValue:@"1500" forKey:@"limit"];
    [params setValue:@"results" forKey:@"callback"];
```

when im using this coding im getting my friend status...

but when im using a dynamic value like this :

```
[params setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", a] forKey:@"uid"];
```

im getting this error

The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

looking forward for your help guys...

im getting this error when generating result array of my friend status...

```
{"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid API key","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"status.get"},{"key":"sdk","value":"ios"},{"key":"uid","value":"524*****"},{"key":"callback","value":"results"},{"key":"limit","value":"15"},{"key":"format","value":"json"}]}
```

plzz  help about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `a` is not NSString subclass